# Why my own created apache config file is not showing colorful text for directive keywords with vim

Tags: vim, apache-http-server

I have centoS operating system.

I am creating my own apache config file like `/usr/local/apache/conf/my.conf`

There are more files like `httpd.conf` and `php.conf` in that directory

Now when i see those files then keywords of apache directives like `LoadModule` are shown in different colors. But in my created conf file tey show like normal text.

Why is that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the relevant part from my (unmodified) `filetype.vim`:

```
" Apache config file
au BufNewFile,BufRead .htaccess,/etc/httpd/*.conf        setf apache
au BufNewFile,BufRead httpd.conf*,srm.conf*,access.conf*,apache.conf*,apache2.conf*,/etc/apache2/*.conf*,/etc/httpd/conf.d/*.conf* call s:StarSetf('apache')
```

As you can see, it only matches specific `.conf` files such as `httpd.conf`, and `.conf` files in particular directories. This is because Apache is not the only software that uses `.conf` files.

You can either add an autocommand for your own `.conf` file, or if this is just a one-off, run `:setf apache`.

Comment: I did that , it worked for time being but when i opened file again. it was lost. how can i use auto command u mentioned

Comment: Just look at the two lines I included. (`au` is shorthand for `autocmd`). See `:help au` for details.

Comment: I tried this but gies error `au BufNewFile,BufRead /usr/local/apache/conf/*.conf        setf apache`

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: in red color they say `no such group or event`. i am executing by going in file with `vim my.conf` then `:command` at bottom. is that right

Comment: You should put it in `~/.vim/ftdetect` or similar. `:help ftdetect` has a nice guide.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a modeline in the top or bottom 5 lines of your config files:

```
# vim: set filetype=apache:
```

See "`:help modeline`".